# Extracting week number from timestamp in Python

Tags: python

I have timestamps in the format

```
          Sep 12 2019 21:28:11
1         Sep 12 2019 21:28:11
2         Oct 13 2019 21:28:11
3         Oct 14 2019 21:28:11
4         Nov 15 2019 21:28:11
```

I need to write a python script by which I can get the week number from the date mentioned. Can anyone help me with the same?

Answer (score 1):

Use `datetime` module.

```py
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("Sep 12 2019 21:28:11", "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%V")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option may be isocalendar function https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isocalendar

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("Sep 12 2019 21:28:11", "%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S").isocalendar()
(2019, 37, 4)
```